# Decrypt java (DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding) cipher using python

Tags: java, python, encryption

Is it possible to implement like this technique in java (encryption and Decryption) using python ?

Here the 3DES is using in this java code.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
String keytext = "key......";
byte[] keyArray = keytext.getBytes("utf-8");
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyArray, "DESede");

String mytext = "anytext......";
Cipher.init(1, key);
byte[] enc = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("utf-8"));
String value = Base64.getUrlEncode().encodeToString(enc);
return value;
```

Hope someone can assist me with this, to implement this using python2 if possible or python3

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

while True:
  try:
    key = DES3.adjust_key_parity(get_random_bytes(24))
    break
  except ValueError:
    pass

cipher = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_CFB)
plaintext = b'We are no longer the knights who say ni!'
msg = cipher.iv + cipher.encrypt(plaintext)

print(msg)
```

Taken from the PyCryptodome manual itself: [Link](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/des3.html)

Comment: pycrypto is not supported anymore, pycryptodome is the follow-on project.  Most likely this code would run unchanged with pycryptodome.

Comment: Thanks @Snix, I am looking for decryption way using python more than the encryption please

Comment: Dude, just check the manual, you have to simply reverse the mechanism using the decrypt method